# How to change primeNG datatable p-column filter date format?

Tags: angular, primeng

How and is it possible to change date format when filtering by date?

```
<p-columnFilter type="date" [field]="col.field" display="menu">
```

Default format is **mm/dd/yyyy** but I want to achieve **dd/mm/yyyy**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far I haven't posted an answer so here is the one I managed to get it work. I've used pTemplate and inside a template I used p-calendar component to change date format.

```
<p-columnFilter [type]="col.type" [field]="col.field" display="menu" [showMatchModes]="true" [showOperator]="false" [showAddButton]="false">
     <ng-template pTemplate="filter" let-value let-filter="filterCallback">
          <p-calendar #calendar [ngModel]="value" (onSelect)="filter(calendar.value)" (onInput)="setup(calendar.value, col.field)" dateFormat="dd.mm.yy"></p-calendar>
     </ng-template>
</p-columnFilter>
```

and in typescript I setup a filter value using ViewChild on table like this:

```
@ViewChild("dt") dataTableComponent: Table;

setup(value, id){
   if(value != null)
     this.dataTableComponent.filters[id][0].value = value;
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by configuring the PrimeNgConfig:

in your i18n assets (could also be just a typescript constant):

```
"primeng": {
    ...
    "dateFormat": "dd.mm.yy",
    ...
 }
```

Then inject `PrimeNgConfig` in your app components constructor:

```
private primeNgConfig: PrimeNGConfig
```

In ngOnInit you can set the configuration:

```
this.translate.get('primeng').subscribe(res => this.primeNgConfig.setTranslation(res))
```

More documentation on here:
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/i18n

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to set certain format for every p-calendar, in your main.ts add this:

```
import { Calendar } from 'primeng/calendar';
Calendar.prototype.getDateFormat = () => 'dd/mm/yy';
```

It's just an ugly hack, because things like this should be configurable somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using "p-columnFilter" component, this means that you are inside the p-table, and you want to filter the value according to the  filter

**You can use this:**

```
<p-table dataKey="id">
   <ng-template pTemplate="header">
       <tr>
            <th>Data</th>

            <th>Name</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
            <th>
               <p-columnFilter type="date" field="date" matchMode="is">
                    <ng-template pTemplate="filter" let-filter="filterCallback">
                       <p-calendar (onSelect)="filter($event)" dateFormat="dd/mm/yy"></p-calendar>
                    </ng-template>
               </p-columnFilter>
            </th>

            <th>
               <p-columnFilter type="text" field="name"></p-columnFilter>
            </th>
       </tr>
   </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Explanation:

I am customizing the Design of the field filter, to accomplish this:

Within "p-columnFilter" I add (ng-content) the  with the pTemplate directive set to "filter".

I also get the "filterCallback" function aliased to "filter"

**Example code:**

```
<p-columnFilter type="date" field="date" matchMode="is">
  <ng-template pTemplate="filter" let-anyname="filterCallback">
      //Custom Design (Example p-calendar, or any other)
      Data:
      <input type="text" (change)="anyname($event.value)"></input>
  </ng-template>
</p-columnFilter>
```

The "anyname" function is the alias for the "filterCallback" function, and when called, the filter of the p-columnFilter component will be applied.

What I'm doing is: customizing the Design and calling the filter (filterCallback) of the p-columnfFilter component with a certain value

If you still have any questions, please comment that I will try to help;

**Important:** You can format only the date display using the PrimeNG component called: , with the dateFormat input

**Example:**

```
<p-calendar dateFormat="dd.mm.yy"></p-calendar>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<p-columnFilter [field]="filter_field">
  <ng-template pTemplate="filter" let-value let-filter="filterCallback">
    <p-calendar #fd [ngModel]="value" dataType="date" dateFormat="dd/mm/yyyy" [showIcon]="false" [showOnFocus]="false(onBlur)="filter(fd.value)"></p-calendar>
  </ng-template>
</p-columnFilter>
```

It seem to work for me

Comment: Please provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Please indent your code.