# Angular - PrimeNG Filter Table - Date Popup Showing Under Table

Tags: angular, date, filter, primeng

I am using a PrimeNG table with filtering, a few of the columns are dates, the popup works fine but if I only have a few rows in the table the calendar popup shows under the table.

I have had a look at z-index etc, but I cannot work out how to solve this issue.

[image]

```
<p-table #budgetTab [value]="budgets" dataKey="id"
       [rows]="10" [showCurrentPageReport]="true" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10,25,50]" [loading]="loading"
       [paginator]="true" currentPageReportTemplate="Showing {first} to {last} of {totalRecords} entries"
       [globalFilterFields]="['department.name','start','end','periodString','dateApproved']" [tableStyle]="{'min-width':'75rem'}">
<ng-template pTemplate="caption">
  <div class="flex">
            <span class="p-input-icon-left p-ml-auto">
                <i class="pi pi-search"></i>
                <input pInputText type="text" placeholder="Search keyword" />
            </span>
  </div>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="header" style="z-index: 1">
  <tr>
    <th style="width:20%">Dept</th>
    <th style="width:20%">Start</th>
    <th style="width:20%">End</th>
    <th style="width:20%">Period</th>
    <th style="width:20%">Approved</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <p-columnFilter type="text" field="department.name"></p-columnFilter>
    </th>
    <th>
      <p-columnFilter type="date" field="start"></p-columnFilter>
    </th>
    <th>
      <p-columnFilter type="date" field="end"></p-columnFilter>
    </th>
    <th>
      <p-columnFilter type="text" field="periodString"></p-columnFilter>
    </th>
    <th>
      <p-columnFilter type="date" field="dateApproved"></p-columnFilter>
    </th>
  </tr>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-budget>
  <tr>
    <td>
      {{budget.department.name | titlecase}}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{budget.start | date: 'mediumDate'}}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{budget.end | date: 'mediumDate'}}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{budget.periodString}}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{budget.dateApproved | date: 'mediumDate'}}
    </td>
  </tr>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="emptymessage">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5">No budgets found.</td>
  </tr>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like many PrimeNg components, you can set their html property appendTo to body like so (appendTo="body"). For the date column, set a p-calendar wrapped in ng-template (you can find an example on how to do it here: [How to change primeNG datatable p-column filter date format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66884173/how-to-change-primeng-datatable-p-column-filter-date-format)). Add appendTo="body" to it, this will make the element appear above its parent.